# Recurrences (based on Fibonacci numbers) for the first differences of numbers filtred by equality of binary functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, fibonacci-numbers

First we need to set some binary functions:

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), i.e., $1$'s-counting sequence: number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$).

Let $\operatorname{val}(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), i.e., exponent of highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, a.k.a. the binary carry sequence, the ruler sequence, or the $2$-adic valuation of $n$.

After that we need to set some functions based on Fibonacci numbers:

Let $f(n)$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045), i.e., Fibonacci numbers: $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Let $g(n)$ be [A010056](https://oeis.org/A010056), i.e., characteristic function of Fibonacci numbers: $a(n) = 1$ if $n$ is a Fibonacci number, otherwise $0$.

Let $h(n)$ be [A072649](https://oeis.org/A072649), i.e., $n$ occurs $f(n)$ times.

Let $s(n)$ be a permutation of natural numbers, such that each $f(n)$ natural numbers are sorted in descending order. Here
$$s(n)=f(h(n)+3)-n-1$$

Now we are ready to start:

Let $a_1(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $k$ such that
$$\operatorname{wt}(k)=\operatorname{val}(k)+2$$

Let
$$b_1(n)=\begin{cases}
2^{n-1},&\text{if $n<4$;}\\
5,&\text{if $g(n-1)=1$;}\\
2b_1(n-f(h(n-1)+1))-[g(n)=1],&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

**Conjecture**: $a_1(n)=a_1(n-1)+b_1(n)$ with $a_1(1)=3$.

Let $a_2(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $k$ such that
$$\ell(k-1)-\operatorname{wt}(k-1)=\operatorname{val}(k)$$
with $a_2(1)=1$ prepended.

Let
$$b_2(n)=\begin{cases}
2^{n-1},&\text{if $n<4$;}\\
5,&\text{if $g(n)=1$;}\\
2b_2(s(s(n)-f(h(n)+1)+1)+1)-[g(n-1)=1],&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

**Conjecture**: $a_2(n)=a_2(n-1)+b_2(n)$ with $a_2(1)=1$.

Is there a way to prove it?